# PhoneGap 3.0: `phonegap platform build android` returns success but buildfile doesn't exist

Tags: cordova

Using Windows 7. Walking through the process in [PhoneGap documentation here,](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) I'm eventually stuck on the step of creating the project using Eclipse, but the root cause seems to be happening in the build step. Running it normally, I get a response that indicates success, but with the -V flag, I see this output:

```
 C:\Development\local>phonegap local build android -V
 [phonegap] compiling Android...
 [phonegap] cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
 [phonegap] Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
 cp: dest file already exists: C:\Development\local\platforms\android\assets\www\phonegap.js
 [phonegap] Compiling platform "android" with command ""C:\Development\local\platforms\android\cordova\build"" (output to follow)...
 [phonegap] Cleaning project...
 WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debug.
 Buildfile: C:\Development\local\platforms\android\build.xml does not exist!
 Build failed
 [phonegap] Platform "android" compiled successfully.
 [phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

I believe all my PATH variables are set up correctly, and the only other thing I saw here or on the phonegap list indicated there was a problem with this when the project name included spaces, though mine doesn't.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the problem was a badly-formed config file stemming from the fact that I created the project incorrectly, leaving out the quotes in:
    $ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"

Comment: What is different, beetween with and without quotes ?

Comment: It led to the config file being written with some elements unreadable by phonegap. I cleared out all the broken parts already or I'd be able to provide examples.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. 
I opened a lot of issues on cli, both on cordova and phonegap, last of this is: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/147